# A sub condition inside FILTER using a non related table

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

I have two tables Rec and DD as below and they do not have any relationships:

The table Rec with two fields:

```
Date        col1
-------     -----
1/1/2019    1
12/12/2018  2
15/5/2019   3
1/1/2019    4
12/12/2018  5
15/5/2019   6
```

The table DD with two fields:

```
Date        Flag
-------     -----
1/1/2019    true
12/12/2018  false
15/5/2019   false
```

I would please like to find out the sum of Rec[col1] where the Rec[Date] = DD[Date] and DD[Flag] is TRUE. There should only be one inctance where this boolean field is TRUE.

I was thiking something like below but not sure how to finish writing it:

```
calculate(
    SUM(Rec[col1])
    , filter(Rec, Rec[Date] = { date from DD where Flag is TRUE   }
    )
)
```

Also tried the below but that is not working as well:

```
var sd= CALCULATE(max(dd[date]), filter(DD, dd[Flag] = TRUE()))
return

    calculate(
        SUM(Rec[col1])
        , filter(Rec, Rec[Date] = sd
        )
    )
```

**Edit 1:**

I should have mentioned that Flag is a Measure:

```
Flag = if( max(DD[Date]) = SELECTEDVALUE(SlicerV[Date]),
    True,
    FALSE
)
```

**Edit 2**

I am using the date selected with the **slicer** to give me the date required.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to this problem. 
Instead of a CALCULATED column I have created a MEASURE to do the same and it is a lot simpler as simple as

```
Measure = sum(rec(col1]))
```

This automatically applied the FILTER CONTEXT.

So a lesson learned: "instead of a calculated column first try to find out if it can be done with a measure".